# BASH Array indexing minus the last array

Tags: arrays, bash

Here is a problem which bothers me - I need to read version number from user input, and I'd like to create a "menu" using the length of the array storing the version numbers. However, BASH's mysterious syntax is not helping me here:

```
echo $VERSIONS
2.0.10-1 2.0.7-1 2.0.7-1 2.0.7-1 2.0.10-1

for v in ${!VERSIONS[*]}
do
  echo "$(($v+1))) ${VERSIONS[$v]}  "
done
```

output

```
1) 2.0.10-1
   2.0.7-1
   2.0.7-1
   2.0.7-1
   2.0.10-1  
2) 2.0.7-1  
3) 2.0.7-1  
4) 2.0.7-1  
5) 2.0.10-1
```

another command

```
for v in ${!VERSIONS[*]}
do
  echo "$(($v+1))) ${VERSIONS[$v+1]}  "
done

1) 2.0.7-1  
2) 2.0.7-1  
3) 2.0.7-1  
4) 2.0.10-1  
5)
```

What I'd really like to have is an output like that:

```
1) 2.0.7-1  
2) 2.0.7-1  
3) 2.0.7-1  
4) 2.0.10-1
```

with out the last 5)....

Would be happy to unravel how to do it in bash...

P.S. A colleague of mine just offered a way without arrays. I'm posting it just for fun:

```
i=1
for v in $VERSIONS
do
  echo "$i) $v" ; i=$(($i+1))
done
```

output

```
1) 2.0.10-1
2) 2.0.7-1
3) 2.0.7-1
4) 2.0.7-1
5) 2.0.10-1
```

OK, since the solutions don't work inside my script I will post some more info:

```
for package in $NEWPACKAGES 
do  
    apt-show-versions -a -p $package
    VERSIONS=$(apt-show-versions -a -p $package | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -d " " -f 1)
    echo $VERSIONS
    echo "type the number for version you want to install: (type enter to skip)"

    for i in `seq 1 ${#VERSIONS[@]}`; do 
    echo "$i) ${VERSIONS[$(($i-1))]}"; 
done

    echo $VERSIONS    
    read version
    echo "your choice $version"
    # now the problem is that i can't get this part to work !
    apt-get install $package="${#VERSIONS[$version]}"
done
```

Comment: Actually your first variant works perfectly fine with me. Maybe you just forgot a declare -a to mark $VERSIONS as real array? Looks like it's just a string of words.

Comment: Hi Speckinius, I have added how the VERSIONS is created, I don't know how to make it a real array, comments would be appreciated

Comment: @Oz123 my answer showed you that you can create an array by `array=($VERSIONS)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A version with arrays, if you still need one.

```
for i in `seq 1 ${#VERSIONS[@]}`; do 
    echo "$i) ${VERSIONS[$(($i-1))]}"; 
done
```

Comment: versions is not really and array, i get it like this: VERSIONS=$(apt-show-versions -a -p $package | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -d " " -f 1)

Comment: @Oz123 What happens if you change it into `VERSIONS=($(apt-show-versions -a -p $package | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -d " " -f 1))`?

Comment: OK your solution is working: it produces a menu. But I can't get     apt-get install $package="${#VERSIONS[$version]}"
to work... it is still behaving oddly...

Comment: @Oz123 Shouldn't that be `${VERSIONS[$version]}`?

Comment: @Le_Me_Be don't think so, right now any echo $VERSIONS just returns a single number .... so it is not an array any more...

Comment: OK, the script is working, now I can easily fix multiple over-upgraded debian packages from multiple sources. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

So indeed you are looking for a away to convert a normal variable to an array, here it is:

```
array=($VERSIONS)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
VERSIONS=(2.0.10-1 2.0.7-1 2.0.7-1 2.0.7-1 2.0.10-1) 
for i in ${!VERSIONS[@]} ; do echo "$(($i+1))] ${VERSIONS[i]}"; done
```