# How to remove the last element of an array in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

The syntax to delete an element from an array can be found here: [Remove an element from a Bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860877/remove-an-element-from-a-bash-array)

Also, here is how to find the last element of an array: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198787/is-there-a-way-of-reading-the-last-element-of-an-array-with-bash

**But how can I mix them (if possible) together to remove the last element of the array ?**

I tried this:

```
TABLE_COLUMNS=${TABLE_COLUMNS[@]/${TABLE_COLUMNS[-1]}}
```

But it throws:

> bad array subscript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I subtract 1 from an array item in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745252/how-do-i-subtract-1-from-an-array-item-in-bash)

Comment: @bobdylan That question is about subtracting 1 from one element, this question is about removing an element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174354/bash-array-indexing-minus-the-last-array - wouldn't let me flag more than one question

Comment: Notice that your code works in Bash 4.3 or newer, but it has the (big) flaw of not removing complete elements, but also substring matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: This is useful for printing elements except the last without altering the array. See [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60832964/10248678) for a far more convenient solution to OP.

---

Substring expansions<sup>*</sup> could be used on arrays for extracting subarrays, like:

```
TABLE_COLUMNS=("${TABLE_COLUMNS[@]::${#TABLE_COLUMNS[@]}-1}")
```

<sup>*</sup> The syntax is:

```
${parameter:offset:length}
```

Both `offset` and `length` are arithmetic expressions, an empty `offset` implies `1`. Used on array expansions (i.e. when `parameter` is an array name subscripted with `*` or `@`), the result is at most `length` elements starting from `offset`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unset` to remove a specific element of an array given its position.

```
$ foo=(1 2 3 4 5)
$ printf "%s\n" "${foo[@]}"
1
2
3
4
5
$ unset 'foo[-1]'
$ printf "%s\n" "${foo[@]}"
1
2
3
4
```